# Pseudo Table entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rubygems

I'm a learning developer building a Product & Inventory tracking platform for the company I work at and my Rails application has a `Products` table.  Within the `Products` table are a bunch of basic entries, such as `SKU`, `Description`, `UPC`, `Manufacturer`, etc.

What I want to do is have an option within the `Create` page to insert custom parameters into something like a text_area to create Product specific entries, for example if I have only a small set of products that would benefit from a `Voltage` column and don't want to flood my migration with a bunch of lesser used options.  What I'm picturing:

```
'Voltage|120 Volts'
'Housing Material|Steel'
'Duct Size|4"'
```

and then these could be their own rows in the Product's `Show` page.

Is anybody aware of a Gem or template that already accomplishes this, or would I need to dive in the deep end myself?  I fear something like this is out of my skillset currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one [hstore](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html) column in the migration which will allow you to store multiple dynamic values in the single column as a hash.

You can read more about hstore from [here](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-hstore-with-rails).

I used hstore to store dynamic variants of product in the table.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  In all the examples I could find on hstore, when querying, they make the assumption that the key is going to be pre-defined, such as this example:  `User.where("preferences ? :key", key: "github")`.  Would it be possible to do an `each` loop on any key/value pair that happens to be in the column?

Comment: yes you can simply use .each directly on hstore column if hstore column is not part of your where query lets take an example. if you have user object which contains hstore column. you can iterate over like this 
user = User.where("your query")
#code
user.prefrences.each do |key, value|
#your code
end

hstore has all properties of hash data structure

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the guidance in the right direction!